# Proof that a field is an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

Here is my attempt at proving this.

Let $F$ be a field and let $a \in F, \ a \neq 0$.

Then $a$ is a unit and hence $\exists \ b \in F$ such that $ab = 1$

Now let $c \in F, \ c \neq 0$

Let $a \cdot c = 0$

Then $b \cdot a \cdot c = b \cdot 0$

$\implies 1 \cdot c = c = 0$

This is a contradiction as $c \neq 0$

Hence $a \cdot c \neq 0$

I.e. F is an integral domain.

Does that look ok? Any ideas on how to show it without using a contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks just fine. I would say $b\cdot a=1$ rather than $ab=1,$ though, to make it all perfectly clear.

To proceed without contradiction, simply remove the assumption that $c\ne 0.$ Then $a\cdot c=0$ implies $b\cdot (a\cdot c)=b\cdot 0,$ which implies (if you've shown/seen that $0$ is multiplicatively absorptive) by associativity that $1\cdot c=0,$ so $c=0$. This shows that if $a\in F$ with $a\ne 0,$ then the *only* $c\in F$ such that $a\cdot c=0$ is $c=0$. Consequently, it is not possible for the product of two non-$0$ elements of $F$ to be $0,$ so $F$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 2):

You could just assume that $a$ is invertible with $ba=1$ and that $a⋅c=0$ for some $c\in F$. Then $$c=1⋅c=ba⋅c=b⋅ac=b⋅0=0$$ so $c$ must be $0$. But the definition of a *zero divisor* $a$ says that $a⋅c=0$ for some non-zero $c$. In other words, $a$ is not a zero divisor. Since $a$ was an arbitrary field element, this means that $F$ has no zero divisors.

A similar proof shows that an invertible $r$ in a ring $R$ cannot give the product $0$ when multiplied with a non-zero module element $m$, as $m=1\cdot m=r^{-1}⋅r⋅m=r^{-1}⋅0=0$

Answer (score 1):

This is the right idea, but I'd recommend changing a couple things:

- Change the "Let" in "Let $a\cdot c = 0$ to "Suppose that", "Assume", or something to that effect. (You've already defined $a$ and $c$, and so "let" is a bit awkward here.) This is a technicality but definitely helps with the "flow" of your argument.
- Don't argue by contradiction when you don't have to. If you remove the assumption that $c \neq 0$, then what you've shown is that $a\neq 0$ in $F$ and $ac = 0 \implies c = 0$, which (by definition) shows that $F$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Cheers, yes I want to start being able to prove more things without going down the route of contradiction, using contradiction often feels like the 'easy way out'.

Comment: Actually, in general, what is the correct situation for using 'Let' as opposed to 'Suppose'? I want to be as technically correct as possible.

Comment: I would contend that it is largely a matter of taste, but "suppose" allows that what we are supposing may end up not being true, after all, while "let" has a note of certainty to it.

Comment: @AlgebraGuy: Good for you re. contradiction! The constructivists out there will thank you! `:)` The fact that you can convert the above argument to a proof of the contrapositive is indicative of a general pattern: many proofs by contradiction of a claim can be converted into proofs of the contrapositive. It isn't always going to be the case (or easy to do, or worth doing), but when it is a proof by contrapositive is usually clearer...at least IMO.

Comment: @AlgebraGuy: As Cameron Buie said, this really is a matter of opinion/convention. That said, you'll usually encounter "let" being used as a synonym for "define", whereas "suppose" and "assume" are often used (in addition to definitions) when adding on hypotheses. So for example, if $x$ has yet to be defined/introduced in an argument, then "let $x \in S$", "suppose $x\in S$", and "assume $x\in S$" all are fine. (Also, compound statements like "let $x \in S$ such that [other statements about $x$]" are very common.) [ctd...]

Comment: @AlgebraGuy: [...ctd] On the other hand, if someone has already introduced $x$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}$ earlier in a paper and now wants to, say, treat the case where $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ separately, then he/she might say something like "suppose that $x \in \mathbb{Q}$" (or if it's going to be a short argument/one sentence "if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then ..."), but it's much less common to see "let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ in this situation. At least in the journals/books in my field.